# SQL: find count of duplicates, new values added, and values removed in the same table (dynamically)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I'm hoping to complete the goals below using **SQL**:

**1) Find # of duplicated records**
Extract number of repeated values based on a column, which is a "snapshot date", comparing that against previous date
**2) Find # of records added** 
**3) Find # of records removed**

## **See sample tables below:**

Current Table

```
snapshot_date | unique ID
 2018-08-15        1
 2018-08-15        2
 2018-08-15        3
 2018-08-15        4
 2018-08-15        5

 2018-08-16        1
 2018-08-16        3
 2018-08-16        4
 2018-08-16        6
 2018-08-16        7
 2018-08-16        8
 2018-08-16        9

 2018-08-17        3
 2018-08-17        8
 2018-08-17        10
 2018-08-17        11
 2018-08-17        12
 2018-08-17        13
```

Desired Table

```
snapshot date | count | # of dupe from previous date | sum of ID added | sum of ID removed
 2018-08-15       5                 N/A                     N/A                  N/A 
 2018-08-16       7                  3                       4                    2
 2018-08-17       6                  2                       4                    5
```

If anyone knows the script to get to the desired table, I'd be so  appreciative! Thank ya'll in advance!

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server?  They're not the same thing.  Is this homework?

Comment: Please share what you have tried

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm actually using company's internal SQL language, which, I believe, have some similar syntax to MySQL.

Comment: @Squirrel I tried a bunch of weird combination of queries, and they were obviously wrong, because it would yield results like "NULL" for all rows...

Comment: What is the `sum of ID added` for `2018-08-16` 4, and not 3?  It looks to me like only 3 new values are coming in versus the previous day?

Comment: Basically, you're going to need to do one or more self joins here, followed by an aggregation.  But, there are enough problems with your data to make me pause before attempting an answer.

Comment: `company's internal SQL language`- so it is a proprietary and not a commercial database ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen for `2018-08-16`, there are 4 new values comparing against the values from previous day , which are 6, 7, 8, and 9.

Comment: @Squirrel Yes I believe so :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is my take. based on SQL Server

```
SELECT  snapshot_date       = COALESCE(c.snapshot_date, DATEADD(day, 1, p.snapshot_date)),
        [count]             = COUNT(c.snapshot_date),
        dup_from_prev_day   = SUM(CASE WHEN c.snapshot_date is not null 
                                       AND  p.snapshot_date is not null 
                                       THEN 1 END),
        sum_of_id_added     = SUM(CASE WHEN c.snapshot_date is not null 
                                       AND  p.snapshot_date is null 
                                       THEN 1 END),
        sum_of_id_removed   = SUM(CASE WHEN c.snapshot_date is null 
                                       AND  p.snapshot_date is not null 
                                       THEN 1 END)
FROM    yourTable c         -- current
        FULL OUTER JOIN yourTable p -- previous
        ON  c.snapshot_date     = DATEADD(DAY, 1, p.snapshot_date)
        AND c.uniqueID          = p.uniqueID
GROUP BY COALESCE(c.snapshot_date, DATEADD(DAY, 1, p.snapshot_date))
HAVING COUNT(c.snapshot_date) > 0

/* RESULT : 
snapshot_date  count  dup_from_prev_day  sum_of_id_added  sum_of_id_removed
2018-08-15     5      NULL               5                NULL
2018-08-16     7      3                  4                2
2018-08-17     6      2                  4                5
*/
```

Comment: This is probably the way to go, assuming the OP's database supports full outer joins.

Comment: OP is working at Google, wonder what is the in-house database.

Comment: I'm wondering why a Google engineer is asking this question on Stack Overflow :-) ... +1 to you anyway.

Comment: Did some googling and found out about Google's `spanner`

Comment: @Jenny Cheers on learning SQL, and you asked a fairly good question, as things go here on the site.

Comment: Thank you to you both for coming up with a solution so promptly! This is my first time posting a question, and it's awesome to see such a supportive and brilliantly smart community.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using MySQL, which, at least in earlier versions, does not support the analytic functions LEAD and LAG, then one approach would be to do a series of self joins followed by an aggregation to get results you want:

```
SELECT
    t1.snapshot_date,
    t1.count,
    t1.previous_dupe,
    t1.num_added,
    t2.num_subtracted
FROM
(
    SELECT
        t1.snapshot_date,
        COUNT(*) AS count,
        COUNT(t2.snapshot_date) AS previous_dupe,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN t2.snapshot_date IS NULL THEN 1 END) AS num_added
    FROM yourTable t1
    LEFT JOIN yourTable t2
        ON t1.snapshot_date = DATE_ADD(t2.snapshot_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND
           t1.uniqueID = t2.uniqueID
    GROUP BY t1.snapshot_date
) t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT
        DATE_ADD(t1.snapshot_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS snapshot_date,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN t2.snapshot_date IS NULL THEN 1 END) AS num_subtracted
    FROM yourTable t1
    LEFT JOIN yourTable t2
        ON t1.snapshot_date = DATE_SUB(t2.snapshot_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND
           t1.uniqueID = t2.uniqueID
    GROUP BY t1.snapshot_date
) t2
    ON t1.snapshot_date = t2.snapshot_date;
```

[image]

### Demo

Notes: There is a slight discrepancy between my results and what you expect, partly due to your own math error, and partly due to the way the logic in the query works.  I report 5 new IDs being added in the earliest record, because conceptually there was no earlier record, and all 5 values are techincally new.

This problem was particularly ugly because we needed to self join twice, in two separate subqueries, in different directions.